# Add Roles to AppRegistration and Assign users to Roles

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-identity-platform

Currently, I'm trying to add an AppRole to my new AppRegistration in the Azure AD B2C resource accordingly to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps). Unfortunately, I am not able to see that option neither the one that allows me to assign users to roles. I had to add the appRole manually by modifying the manifest of the appRegistration but that's all I could do.

Does anyone have any idea ? It looks for me that the documentation is not updated.

[image: Azure AD Bc2]

Answer (score 1):

That documentation is for Azure AD, not B2C.

One way to do something similar is via [Graph API](https://mrochon.azurewebsites.net/2019/05/06/using-groups-in-azure-ad-b2c/).